# Use \foreach in non-Tikz context

Tags: tikz-pgf, footnotes, foreach

I want to create my own footnote-command for floating environments:

```
%begin figure
bla\myFootnote{XXX}
blabla\myFootnote{YYY}
blabla\myFootnote{ZZZ}
%end figure
some text
\printSavedFootnotes
```

The commands are:

```
\global\def\footnoteStore{}
\global\def\footnoteSeparator{}
\global\def\firstSkip{1}


\newcommand{\myFootnote}[1]{\addtocounter{footnote}{\firstSkip}\footnotemark[\thefootnote]
 \global\edef\footnoteStore{\footnoteStore\footnoteSeparator\thefootnote/#1}    
 \addtocounter{footnote}{1}
 \global\edef\footnoteSeparator{,}
 \global\edef\firstSkip{0}
}

\newcommand{\printSavedFootnotes}{
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i/\j in{\footnoteStore}{
    \footnotetext[\i]{\j}
  }
  \global\edef\footnoteStore{}
  \global\edef\footnoteSeparator{}  
 \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

But for the `\foreach` I have to use `\tikzpicture`, and then there can not be used `\footnotetext` :(

Is there any solution to use `\foreach` outside of the box or use the `\footnotetext` inside of tikzpicture?

Thanks :)

Comment: No you don't have to. You don't even have to load TikZ. `\usepackage{pgffor}` is enough.

Comment: when I use `\usepackage{pgffor}`  and delete `\begin{tikzpicture}` `\end{tikzpicture}` it doesn't work :/

Comment: doesn't work how?

Comment: Have you considered using the [`endnotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/endnotes)-package?

Comment: ´\printSavedFootnotes´ inserts `/XXX,11/YYY,12/ZZZ` into the main content area. Furthermore there is only one ´footnotetext ´set, with: `10 10/XXX,11/YYY,12/ZZZ` (counter starts with 10)

Comment: @percusse maybe i'm doing it wrong.... can you give me an example?

Comment: BTW, you can do all this with native TeX commands line \loop \ifnum \repeat and \csname.  Or better yet you could write all this info to the aux file.

Comment: @JohnKormylo , I cant imagine how to do this with the tex commands in a proper way ... .Can you give me an exaple to do this loop with tex commands? Thanks :).

Comment: BTW: the `footnote` package already has a mechanism for this

Answer (score 1):

Note that this resets the footnote index to zero after printing.  If you want non-repeating numbers or to use the footnote counter, that can also be done.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\mycount

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myFootnote}[1]% #1 = text
{\global\advance\mycount by 1
 \@textsuperscript{\@fnsymbol\mycount}
 \global\expandafter\def\csname myfootnote\the\mycount\endcsname{#1}% if #1 contains any macros, use \def not \edef
}
\newcommand{\printSavedFootnotes}%
{\par\bgroup
 \countdef\index=1
 \index=0
 \loop\ifnum\index<\mycount\relax
   \advance\index by 1
   \noindent\hbox to 1em{\@textsuperscript{\@fnsymbol\index}}%
   \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-1em}{\footnotesize\csname myfootnote\the\index\endcsname\strut}\par
 \repeat% no \fi needed
 \egroup
 \global\mycount=0
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
bla\myFootnote{XXX}
blabla\myFootnote{A very very very very very very long footnote in order to demonstrate the hanging indentation.}
blabla\myFootnote{ZZZ}
\end{figure}

some text
\printSavedFootnotes

\end{document}
```

[image: cropped text]